# Unique name for the button with plus sign - want to click this button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

The code is:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="padding:0 5px" id="addPiidRelatedNumberBtn_332741000" ng-click="AddPiidRelatedNumber($event)" ng-show="EnableEditable &amp;&amp; CanEdit">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" title="Add New Related Number"></span>
```

I wrote this selenium code in STS bundle:

```
WaitUtility.ThreadSleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='addPiidRelatedNumberBtn_332741000']")).click();
```

But I know the id can be changed anytime as it has some digits in it. Is there a better way to code this to click this button?

Comment: HTML code is :

<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="padding:0 5px" id="addPiidRelatedNumberBtn_332741000" ng-click="AddPiidRelatedNumber($event)" ng-show="EnableEditable &amp;&amp; CanEdit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" title="Add New Related Number"></span>
                    
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" title="Add New Related Number"></span>

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@id,'addPiidRelatedNumberBtn_')]")).click();
```

You can find more info on XPath use for testing in this article:

[XPath tutorial on guru99](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default.btn-xs>span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus[title='Add New Related Number']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default btn-xs']/span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' and @title='Add New Related Number']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular attribute,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click='AddPiidRelatedNumber($event)']"));
```